# Python: regex to parse URL components

Tags: python, regex

Lets say this is my URL string:

https://stackexchange.com/oauth/login_success/#access_token=xxxxxx))&expires=86400

I want to parse just the access token part "xxxxxx))"

This is what I've done so far:

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse
strr = "https://stackexchange.com/oauth/login_success/#access_token=xxxxxx))&expires=86400"

o = urlparse(strr)

print(o.fragment)
```

The output I'm getting is:

> access_token=xxxxxx))&expires=86400

What's the best way from here to get only the "xxxxxx))" part? Use regex?

Comment: `pydoc3 urllib.parse.parse_qs`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way to do that - first use `urlparse()` and then call `parse_qs()` on the `fragment`:

```
>>> from urllib.parse import parse_qs, urlparse
>>> 
>>> strr = "https://stackexchange.com/oauth/login_success/#access_token=xxxxxx))&expires=86400"
>>> o = parse_qs(urlparse(strr).fragment)
>>> print(o['access_token'])
['xxxxxx))']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression:

```
(?<=access_token=)[^\)]*
```